# Check all list of values are in the enum c#

Tags: c#, linq, enums

I have an integer list containing the ids

```
List<int> ids = new List<int>;
```

I am adding values in the list

```
list.Add(100);
list.Add(110);
list.Add(120);
```

I want to check whether all the values present in the list is present in my enum

```
public enum IdEnum
{
    IT= 100,
    Bank= 110,
    Insurance= 120,
 }
```

Currently I am using

```
if (ids.Select(x => x).All(x => Enum.TryParse(x.ToString(), out IdEnum y)))
{
    //All the companies in the list are present in the enum
}
else
{
}
```

Even if one company in the ids list is different from the enum it should be in else

In my case in both the cases it is executing the if statement.If all the companies are same as enum or if some of the companies are different from enum
ANy help?

Comment: Can't understand last 2 lines.

Comment: My requirement is if all the companies in the id list are in enum then execute if or if any of the one company is not in enum else statement should execute.But the linq I have written in both the cases it is executing the if statement which is wrong.

Answer (score 9):

`Enum.TryParse` returns true for *any* numeric value. As per [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.enum.tryparse?view=netframework-4.7#System_Enum_TryParse__1_System_String___0__):

> If value is the string representation of an integer that does not represent an underlying value of the `TEnum` enumeration, the method returns an enumeration member whose underlying value is value converted to an integral type. If this behavior is undesirable, call the `IsDefined` method to ensure that a particular string representation of an integer is actually a member of `TEnum`.

So following the suggestion, just use `IsDefined`:

```
if (ids.All(x => Enum.IsDefined(typeof(IdEnum), x)))
```

Comment: @Ritesh best way of saying thank you on StackOverflow is to accept the answer that helped you as correct (You haven't accepted any answer on all questions you posted ). If you don't know how to do it [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) can help. An accepted answer can help future people with the same problem to navigate to a working solution much better.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `Except` which is *set* operation instead of searching each id in enum values

```
var allIn = !ids.Except(Enum.GetValues(typeof(IdEnum)).Cast<int>()).Any();
```

When you use [`Enum.IsDefined`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/type.cs,f5e6d204f05b157e) you are doing lot of additional work for each id in list - each values is checked for null, then type of object is verified to be enum, after that type of value is checked, underlying type of enum is checked, array of enum values is retrieved, and binary search in values is performed. That is done for each value.

On the other hand, you can get all enum values only once without additional check of value types. Then just remove these values from list of ids and check if anything left.

Answer (score 2):

```
if (ids.Select(x => x).All(x => Enum.IsDefined(typeof(IdEnum), x)))
{
    // All the companies in the list are present in the enum
}
else
{

}
```